# Basic sound generation/synthesis library, any language

Tags: synthesis, audio

I'm writing a small web app for a music psychology project that will play a series of sound samples for a subject and ask them to rate each one. I need to generate a series of tones (probably all sine waves) with one or two basic filters/effects applied, such as distortion. In effect, I need a simple synthesizer library.

Because it's a web app, I need it to be able to spit out audio files (to play via HTML5 audio), not just play the sounds in real time. I'll be generating these files in advance, not while the app runs, so performance is not an issue.

I'm most comfortable in Python, but the app is simple, so I'm willing to work with pretty much any language. The popular Snack library for Python/Tcl has some basic synthesis facilities but doesn't come with any effects to speak of, besides formants.

The most natural choice would be a sound design language like Csound, Supercollider or ChucK, but it seems like they have a very steep learning curve just to generate sine waves with different frequencies and sometimes a distortion effect.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up sticking with Snack. I suspect nothing exists that meets my criteria. I compromised by creating the "harsh timbre" condition that I had wanted to produce with distortion by mixing a square wave in and a little noise. Doesn't sound great, but there's no specific definition of "harshness" that I'm required to use for the project.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing this beforehand, just use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net). It is able to generate sine/square/sawtooth waves (Generate > Chirp) and has a few effects.  You can then save to a number of compressed formats.

If you're going to be creating a large number of files, you probably don't want to sit and generate each one manually.  Fortunately, Audacity [is scriptable](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=Creating_your_own_Plug-in).

Comment: This looks very decent, but ideally I'd like to be able to have a script that can run on the server side and generate the sound files as well as a JSON file to send down to the client with the list of files, their paths, and some other data about them. With Audacity, every time I want to change the sounds, I have to fire up a desktop app, twiddle with automation scripts, and re-upload the output. Thanks, though--this may be what I end up doing if I can't get what I really want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you define 'simple', but you should look at the [Synthesis Toolkit](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/) library. It's in C++, and one of its authors also has a nice book "[Real Sound Synthesis for Interactive Applications](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~prc/AKPetersBook.htm)" that may also be worth spending some time with.